# composer does not autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, tumblr, autoload, composer-php

I followed the composer instructions and installed composer successfully. I want to use tumblr's brand new [php api client](https://packagist.org/packages/tumblr/tumblr).

My folder structure:

```
vendor/
composer.json
composer.lock
myfile.php
```

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "tumblr/tumblr": "0.0.2"
    }
}
```

`myfile.php`:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

Installing using `php composer.phar install` works great as well. But when executing `myfile.php` the class could not be found.

Fatal error: Class 'Tumblr\API\Client' not found in [..]/htdocs/tumblr/myfile.php on line 9

Comment: That's because they messed up their autoload definition. I've sent a pull request to fix it: https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/pull/1

Comment: You marked this issue as an enhancement on github. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but it's been merged now, so a `composer update` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of tumblr.php has been released which fixes the issue. Thanks to @igorw.