# PHP tumblr API integration with OAUTH

Tags: php, tumblr

I am using following API:-

https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php
I have run composer dependencies within API folder of tumblr. Please let me know that where the file for creating client object will be place.

Where should we place this code:-

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);

[Please check attachment of folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA1z1.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Right at the top of your file after setting the `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, `token`, and `tokenSecret`. So, for instance:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$consumerKey = 'doTy109KhSbt4QKzdYWDns7lIWMhiehHKJ29NNsc6VS0CImPUU';
$consumerSecret = 'AsPvCGXe13Ydvcovu8uCyX4WhNk7chLoGM7bNMpH7hjQgA8FhI';

$tmpToken = isset($_SESSION['tmp_oauth_token'])? $_SESSION['tmp_oauth_token'] : null;
$tmpTokenSecret = isset($_SESSION['tmp_oauth_token_secret'])? $_SESSION['tmp_oauth_token_secret'] : null;

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $tmpToken, $tmpTokenSecret);
```

If you want to see a fully fleshed-out example, see [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/lightsuner/8146768).

Comment: Where should I place your provided php file example? Because I have tried to place it beside the vendor folder. But it saying : Class 'Tumblr\API\Client' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\real\Tumblr\API\tumblr.php on line 13

Comment: @PankajSharma Can you update your question with a folder hierarchy? Print it using the command in the top answer for this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree).

Comment: I have attached attachement of folder hierarchy. Please check and let me know if any more thing required

Comment: I think [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451371/composer-does-not-autoload) will solve your problem.